# Error on Google Colab: Some keys in session_kwargs are not supported at this time

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I am trying to learn about neural networks, I use Google Colab Research to run my notebooks because my computer is not very good.
As you can see from the code below, I am trying to use fit () in my model. To create my model I used Keras, basically I imported Keras's own MNIST dataset, and I was able to create the model as the summary below. But when trying to train the model, you are presenting the error in the first image below the code.

Can you please help me? I think it's some Google Colab setup, because I'm sure the code is correct.

I get the following error:

Code:

```
epochs = 1

history = model.fit(x_train,
                    y_train,
                    batch_size = batch_size,
                    epochs = epochs,
                    verbose = 1,
                    validation_data = (x_test, y_test))

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Error:
[image: Error on Google Colab Research]

Model Summary:
[image: Model Summary]

Comment: In your compile call you have written metric instead of metrics.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro This solved my problem, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section), even though it is present in the Comments Section, for the benefit of the community.

Issue was resolved by replacing `metric` with `metrics` in compile call (typo error).